# WAMP localhost and phpmyadmin setup

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have inherited a WAMP setup, but needed my `http://localhost` to point to a different directory `"C:/Users/[user.name]/htdocs"` due to many dependencies.
I made the following changes in `httpd.conf`

1. `DocumentRoot "C:/Users/[user.name]/htdocs"`
2. `<Directory "C:/Users/[user.name]/htdocs">`

where the original path was `"c:/wamp/www/"`

Now the WAMP default path for phpMyAdmin `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin` is not working anymore.

Is it possible to fix that via either `C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a better solution to your requirement to have a site running that does not live in the WAMPServer default location i.e. `\wamp\www` or `\wamp\www\somefolder`

If you revert all your httpd.conf changes to the out of the box state and then create a Virtual Host to run the site you have located in your `\user....` folder.

Virtual Hosts are a standard Apache feature that allows you to run may sites from a single instance of Apache, a bit like a shared hosting package setup.

You would then have the benefits of the WAMPServer homepage running on `localhost` and all the other alias's tools as well.

You can then run your site using a nice url for example `sitename.dev` and the virtual host definition also allows you to setup any site specific requirements without effecting any other site you may want to run.

There is a HowTo Setup Virtual Hosts [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Thanks Riggs, I was thinking about it as well, but I have some dependencies regarding the URL `http://localhost` as dev env as well. I do see your point, though, and if you say that is the best solution I will revert to that.
Thanks for your input and help.

Comment: Actually I need `http://localhost` to point to this folder as e. g. VirtualBox's `10.0.2.2` is pointing to the host's `http://localhost` ... I know I somehow managed to get something like it setup with XAMPP, but I can't recall exactly how ...